# Gregorian Calendar for Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, gregorian-calendar

Is there a way to get the number of the week of the year (and for the month too) with Windows Phone (Silverlight 8.1) of a certain date? I use this code when I create something with C# but I can't find the class `GregorianCalendar` for Windows Phone. Even if i add `using System.Globalization;` and the class sdhould be supported, i can't use it

```
static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    static GregorianCalendar _gc = new GregorianCalendar();

    public static int GetWeekOfMonth(this DateTime time)
    {
        DateTime first = new DateTime(time.Year, time.Month, 1);
        return time.GetWeekOfYear() - first.GetWeekOfYear() + 1;
    }

    static int GetWeekOfYear(this DateTime time)
    {
        return _gc.GetWeekOfYear(time, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Sunday);
    }
}
```